# Name of authentication where TV shows you code to enter on website?

Tags: authentication, smart-tv

I can't find any good resources about how this kind of authentication scheme works where you open an app on your TV (Plex, Youtube,...) and they show you a code (optional there's also a QR code) and then you go to their website, enter their code and then your TV is logged in.

How does this work and what is it called so I can read more?

The sites they ask you to open and enter the code usually look like this:

https://www.plex.tv/link/

https://www.youtube.com/pair

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if there really is a name for it.

Answer (score 2):

I guess Google is using Oauth2 to pair clients (for example a YouTube client in a SmartTV browser) and server data.

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ForDevices

In other platforms like HbbTV 2.0 the CPA (Cross Platform Authentication) has been proposed as login for limited input devices.

https://tech.ebu.ch/groups/CPA

Other proprietary systems like Gigya uses the same approach, so you can get some info also from their documentation